# LDAP modify active directory multiple OU search

Tags: php, active-directory, ldap

I have this script that works fine when i only use one OU. But as soon as i put the $ldapbase in an array and define multiple OU's it stops working @ the ldap_get_entries and the ldap_modify. I know why but not sure how to modify the code accordingly.

Is there a way of either seaching the whole forest root instead of having to define the OU, or just getting the OU of the samaccountname=$username.

```
 <?php
    $username=$_GET['username']; 

    if(isset($_POST['printpin'])) {

    $printpin=$_POST['printpin'];   
    $domadlogin = 'admin@dom.co.uk';
    $domadpw = 'pass';

    $ldapServer = "dc.dom.co.uk";

    $ldapBase[] = "OU=Users1,DC=dom,DC=co,DC=uk";
    $ldapBase[] = "OU=Users2,DC=dom,DC=co,DC=uk";
    $ldapBase[] = "OU=Users3,DC=dom,DC=co,DC=uk";

    $ds = ldap_connect($ldapServer);
    if (!$ds) {die('Cannot Connect to LDAP server');}

    $ldapBind = ldap_bind($ds,$domadlogin,$domadpw);
    if (!$ldapBind) {die('Cannot Bind to LDAP server');}

    ldap_set_option($ds, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0);
    ldap_set_option($ds, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);

    foreach($ldapBase as $dn){ 
    $sr = ldap_search($ds, $dn, "(samaccountname=$username)");
    }

    $ent= ldap_get_entries($ds,$sr);
    $dn=$ent[0]["dn"];
    $newinfo['primaryTelexNumber']= $printpin;

    $save = ldap_modify($ds, $dn, $newinfo);

    if (!$save) {die('Cannot save to LDAP server');}
    ?>

    <p>Your new PIN number has now been set.</p>
    <p>Username:&nbsp;<?php echo $username; ?><br />PIN:<?php echo $printpin; ?></p>

    <?php
    }
    else {
    ?>

    <p>Username:&nbsp;<?php echo $username; ?></p>
    <form action="pin.php?username=<?php echo $username; ?>" method="POST">
    PIN: <input type="text" name="printpin" title="printpin"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="username" value="<?php echo $username; ?>"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Save">
    </form> 


    <?php
    }
    ?>
```

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should move more code to the **foreach** loop and add some checking like that:

```
foreach ($ldapBase as $dn){ 
    $sr = ldap_search($ds, $dn, "(samaccountname=$username)");
    $ent = ldap_get_entries($ds, $sr);

    if ($ent === false || $ent['count'] === 0)
        continue;

    $dn = $ent[0]['dn'];
    $newinfo['primaryTelexNumber'] = $printpin;

    $save = ldap_modify($ds, $dn, $newinfo);

    if (!$save)
        die('Cannot save to LDAP server');

    break;
}
```

If all OU's should be searched and modified then drop the last **break** in the loop.

Comment: thanks for the reponse, after trying it im getting ldap_modify() [function.ldap-modify]: Modify: Insufficient access in ..... does this select the right OU for the ldap_modify or is it trying to use them all in the for each. I just want to use the OU the user is in and modify their record

Comment: It seems that you don't have the right to modify user entries. Check that you're changing right entry (print $dn). You can also try to modify entries using another tool (ex. Apache Directory Studio). If you can't then you need to fix your LDAP configuration.